# Trying to change the visibility of a hidden value and change it's color with jquery

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things:

1. to target a th:value on a hidden input with jquery and,
2. use jquery to make the th:value visible if the condition evaluates to true, and turn it a specific color using a css selector.

here is the html:

```
 <div class="col dividers">
            <h4 class="h-april">April</h4>
            <div th:each="timeline : ${April}">
                <h3 th:text="${timeline.getJobApplications().getTitle()}"></h3>
                <h3 th:text="${timeline.getJobApplications().getCompany}"></h3>
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${timeline.getKanbanStatus()}">
            </div>
```

I have tried adding both a unique id and name to the hidden input, but I'm at a loss for how to add the logic to see if the boolean check (if the kanban status is in January (=1), it should evaluate to true. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please elaborate more by providing your HTML and jQuery code you have tried so far. Add them in your question.

Comment: I added some more.

Comment: Is this your actual html output on browser? Kindly do inspect element over browser and copy html from there and then paste it. So that We get a clear picture of your HTML

Comment: The solution to what you ask isn't as hard as you think, but it seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), hence the lack of responses. Some things to clarify: 1) you have multiple timelines in ${April} ? 2) Why did you use a hidden input? It is actually part of a form or you needed a default hidden element?